# Drawing a A3 form Diagram in Latex

Tags: tikz-trees, circuitikz, draw

I would like to draw the following image in A3 form using Latex coding.
[image]

Best regards and thanks to all who responded to my request.

Comment: Dear Adam, since there isn't any question, we all wish you the best of luck to do so. When you are done we are very interested in your result.